# Footer renders between navbar and component instead of after the component in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

As the title says, my `footer` is rendering between the `navbar` and component while it should render after the component. I can place the `footer` at the bottom with CSS, but in the Chrome developer console it still renders the component after the footer.

This is how I have the `app.js` setup. It is using `react-router-dom` for client-side routing. The `{this.props.children}` renders the correct component based on the route: `/home`, `/help`, etc..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Navbar from '../containers/navbar';
import Footer from '../containers/footer';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is what I ended up doing per suggestion in comments:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { routerMiddleware, ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';

import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import App from './components/app';
import Navbar from './containers/navbar';
import Footer from './containers/footer';

import Signin from './containers/authentication/signin';
import Signout from './containers/authentication/signout';
import PasswordReset from './containers/authentication/password_reset';
import UsernameRecovery from './containers/authentication/username_recovery';
import Home from './components/home';
import Help from './components/help';

import RequireAuth from './helpers/require_auth';
import LeftSite from './helpers/left_site';

import rootReducer from './reducers';

import styles from '../assets/scss/main.scss';

const history = createHistory();

const initialState = {};
const enhancers = [];
const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const devToolsExtension = window.devToolsExtension

    if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
        enhancers.push(devToolsExtension())
    }
}

const composedEnhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers);
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <App />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/home' component={LeftSite(RequireAuth(Home))} />
                    <Route exact path='/help' component={LeftSite(RequireAuth(Help))} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/username' component={UsernameRecovery} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/password' component={PasswordReset} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/signout' component={Signout} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/signin' component={Signin} />
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Signin} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Comment: When you say "It should render after THE COMPONENT" which component do you mean? The one in the code called `App`, or the one possibly in `this.props.children`?

Comment: The one in `this.props.children`. This loads the various components related to `/auth`, `/home`, `/about`, etc...

Comment: Sorry, don't think I can help. I would perhaps start with trying to just add some extra divs around navbar, footer and children, to see if it makes the hierarchy any clearer.

Or add a new div around the whole existing div, then let put the footer on the same level as the inside div..     Something like this:      <div><innerdiv>nav +  children</innerdiv><Footer /></div>

Comment: Just now getting back to this project. Tried just tried about every combination of `<div>`'ing these things to force the hierarchy and it still comes out with header -> footer -> content

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference. but couldn't Navbar and Footer both be in the routes as well (matching some base url)? Then you'd place the rest of the routes between them, matching the different url-endings that come after the url. Maybe it's functionally the same thing as this, but if the issue is related to the routes being passed as this.children, then maybe this could fix it. Just a thought.

Comment: I ended up doing as you suggested and it appears to work as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Oh? You're welcome! Great to hear it worked out!

Comment: If you want to document the solution for future readers and mark this question as solved, it's possible to answer your own question (instead of having it as an edit in your question): https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per jonahe's suggestion, I ended up moving the `<Navbar />` and `<Footer />` out of the `app.js` file where the various components were being rendered. I moved them into the main `index.js` where my routes are at and ended up with the following.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { routerMiddleware, ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';

import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import App from './components/app';
import Navbar from './containers/navbar';
import Footer from './containers/footer';

import Signin from './containers/authentication/signin';
import Signout from './containers/authentication/signout';
import PasswordReset from './containers/authentication/password_reset';
import UsernameRecovery from './containers/authentication/username_recovery';
import Home from './components/home';
import Help from './components/help';

import RequireAuth from './helpers/require_auth';
import LeftSite from './helpers/left_site';

import rootReducer from './reducers';

import styles from '../assets/scss/main.scss';

const history = createHistory();

const initialState = {};
const enhancers = [];
const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const devToolsExtension = window.devToolsExtension

    if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
        enhancers.push(devToolsExtension())
    }
}

const composedEnhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers);
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <App />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/home' component={LeftSite(RequireAuth(Home))} />
                    <Route exact path='/help' component={LeftSite(RequireAuth(Help))} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/username' component={UsernameRecovery} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/password' component={PasswordReset} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/signout' component={Signout} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/signin' component={Signin} />
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Signin} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.querySelector('.container'));
```